# jQuery MMenu: Links on content part don't work on Android / iPhone / Mobile Phone

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, hyperlink, mmenu

I am using `jQuery MMenu`: All links that I place in the `content` part of the page (not the menu itself), don't seem to work on mobile devices.
The same problem also occurs with Forms as their Submit buttons don't seems to work.

All is fine when I visit the website with a desktop browser, please help.

```
<head>...loading CSS and JS</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div class = "header"> <a href="#menu"></a></div>
    <div class = "content"> <a href=xxxxx>LINKS DONT WORK HERE, WHY?</a></div>
    <nav id="menu"> Menu here .... </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

I included the `<nav>` code in a seperate file that is loaded using `PHP include`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I used a CSS Absolute position tag in the CONTENT area, to position all content exactly in upper left corner. When I removed it, the links work now.

However, still a problem about Forms being placed in the CONTENT area, they appear but nothing happens when you press a submit button.